# Solving $(\alpha + \sum_{f} c_{f})w_{f} - c_{f} \sum_f w_{f} = c_{f} $ w.r.t. $w_f$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $\boldsymbol{u}$ be a vector with length $F$.
Let $\boldsymbol{c}, \boldsymbol{w} \in \mathbb{R}^{F\times1}$ be column vectors with length $F$.

I have the following equation:
$$
(\alpha + \sum_{f} c_{f})w_{f}
-c_{f} \sum_f w_{f}
=
\beta
~c_{f}
$$
where I want to isolate $w_f$ (or the whole vector $\boldsymbol{w}$).

If I express it in matricial form I have:
\begin{align*}
(\alpha + \boldsymbol{u}^T \boldsymbol{c}) w_{f}
- c_{f} \boldsymbol{u}^T \boldsymbol{w}
&=
\beta
\boldsymbol{c}
\end{align*}
And putting it in terms of the whole vector $\boldsymbol{w}$:

\begin{align*}
(\alpha\boldsymbol{u} + \boldsymbol{u}^T \boldsymbol{c}\boldsymbol{u})\odot \boldsymbol{w}
- \boldsymbol{c} \boldsymbol{u}^T \boldsymbol{w}\boldsymbol{u}
&=
\beta
\boldsymbol{c}
\end{align*}
And know I'm stuck. I think the trick is to express the second term as another Hadamard product ($\odot$), then I'll have something like 
$$
(...) \odot\boldsymbol{w} =\beta
\boldsymbol{c}
$$ 
but I don't find the way. Any help?

Comment: $$w=\beta\,\big(\alpha I+(c^Tu)I-cu^T\big)^{-1}c$$

Answer (score 0):

Deduced from @lynn's comment.

First, it can be easily checked that the expression in terms of the whole vector $\boldsymbol{w}$ can be written as:
$$
(\alpha \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{c}\mathbf{I})\mathbf{w} - \mathbf{c}\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{w} = \beta \mathbf{c}
$$
or
$$
(Diag(\alpha) + Diag(\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{c}))\mathbf{w} - Diag(\mathbf{c}\mathbf{u}^T)\mathbf{w} = \beta \mathbf{c}
$$
Since both terms in the left-hand side are matrix products, is clear that we can take the common factor $\mathbf{w}$ and obtain:
$$
(\alpha \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{c}\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{c}\mathbf{u}^T)\mathbf{w} = \beta \mathbf{c}
$$
The term in parentheses is an $F\times F$ matrix. Multiplying by its inverse in the left of both sides, we arrive to the solution
$$
\mathbf{w} = \beta (\alpha \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{c}\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{c}\mathbf{u}^T)^{-1}\mathbf{c}
$$